# How insert same row when it's launch date timing after another userid?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How insert same row when it's launch date timing after another userid ?

[image: This is a image Please check]

```
<?php

if ($statuss == "OK") {


    $resulttut = mysql_query("SELECT (SELECT COUNT(u.`upperuserid`) 
         FROM user u 
         WHERE u.upperuserid = user.usernewid 
     ) as ref,
       usernewid,
       paymentmethod,usersecond,launch,useruniqueextra, mod_date
        from user 
        HAVING (ref <  2 or user.usersecond=0) and user.paymentmethod = 1 and launch=1");

    $rowe = mysql_fetch_array($resulttut);

    $acc = " $rowe[coun]";
    $accc = " $rowe[usernewid]";
    $bssoee = " $rowe[useruniqueextra]";


    $query22 = mysql_query("update user set upperuserid='$accc' where user_name='$username'");

}
?>
```

How insert same row when it's launch date timing  after another userid

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: I used mysql @jarlh

Comment: **Stop** using deprecated `mysql_*`API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`. Alos learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: Ok @Jens Sure I did :)

Comment: "insert same row" means update right?

Comment: @apokryfos Please check my picture what i want. usernewid 1116 launch after all id but it's already show on middle i want when it's launch date after all id it's insert with same usernew id in new row. I didn't know how to do this :(

Comment: Can you provide some more details?

Comment: How can i provide details means. ??

Comment: You can start off by explaining further what your system is for and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: i want row placement change while on launching date. means order by launchdate.

Comment: Means small to larger launch date run.

Comment: you mean adding [`ORDER BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sorting-rows.html) `launchdate` to your query?

Comment: yes system check launchdate timing and then row placement after usernewid 1114 @apokryfos :)

Comment: But is this possible :(